# React-native fetch data REST api going fails on production

Tags: rest, reactjs, react-native

I have to create an app with **[React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)** that's using `REST` API. The API I created is using `Laravel 5.2`.

The app works as expected when I develop it in on `localhost`. I'm using Laravel on `localhost` with a custom port like `192.168.xx.xx:8887`, for the backend page and for the mobile app.

I have install it in my mobile, using Wifi debugger with `react-native` `npm start` command for opening it when there are a change.

The problem appears when I'm hosting my Laravel app on a domain. In this case I'm using `000webhost.com`. The app is so slow on fetching data and the response from fetch callback is empty, even though I input the same thing to my local backend and hosted backend. But when I'm opening the remote debugger, the application is going well again, but it's affecting my `react-native` app perform, because I'm opening the remote debugger.

Are there any solution for this? Must I build my `react-native` to signed-apk first before using hosted react API?

Comment: Are you passing `new Date(string)` to server?

Comment: Nope, i'm just passing an access token via url

Comment: Are you sure that its not met with a fetch error.? Could you post your fetch call also with the question.? And also have you tried the url call in some tool like postman?

Comment: I just didn't know what happen. But when I'm using `toogle tool` on my `react-native` app, they give me a `json stringify` format as well. But when I `parse` that `string` to `json`, they give me an error that I haven't seen before. I solved it in my case by change the hosting place with no change of my code. Thank before budy..

Comment: This error also appear on my web application when I use `ajax request` of `datatables`

Comment: So the issue is fixed?

Comment: I didn't know so well, but I think I will close this one

Answer (score 1):

After looking for a while and much of try. I got the problem is on the hosting. Whenever I call a routes that call using ajax and return a `json stringify`, the page is return `json stringify` format as well, but when I `parse` that `string` to `json`, they got an error (in my case the the error is `unexpected token '?'`).

I have tried to hosting in another domain and now it work like what I expected with no change on my code. I didn't know what going on, but it work on different hosting.

It also happen on my `ajax datatable request`

Answer (score 0):

What is your target platform? Are you serving over HTTPS?

By default, iOS will fail to fetch data over non secure connection, unless you enable it (more on [this here](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/)).

Comment: I'm using android and yes they serving over HTTPS